# "Disk drive for dev/mapper/cryptswap 1 is not ready"

Tags: boot, partitioning

I get the following message on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS i386 during the boot process:

```
Disk Drive for dev/mapper/cryptswap 1 is not ready or not present
```

It will give me the message about 3 times and then finally load but I am also getting internal errors (Last night and this morning I pretty well was flooded with them).

I am completely new to Ubuntu and Linux so am I doing the best I can to learn as quickly I am able but it would really be helpful if I could chat with someone as the machine I have apparently is a bit of a pain in general (HP dc7700sf).

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue. Eventually it turned out that the device in /etc/crypttab was wrong.

The system was installed from a USB pen-drive, so during installation the pen-drive was /dev/sda and the hard disc was /dev/sdb. The swap partition was hence written into /etc/crypttab as /dev/sdb6.
After booting from the harddrive this became /dev/sda6 and the mapper could not find it any more.

To fix this just correct the line in /etc/crypttab to the correct /dev/sd?? or the UUID of the swap partition.

Comment: Thanks for this answer - the hint to replace UUID by `/dev/sdaX` in the `/etc/crypttab` file actually helped in my case (the Puny Geek post uses UUIDs exclusively, and that for some reason prevented the remedy in my case). Other than that, this is a known bug [reported in the Ubuntu bugtracker](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cryptsetup/+bug/1305961?comments=all)

Comment: Hello verwaltungspraxis, It is only one time fix. After second reboot the same message will appear and also when it succeeds first time, if I put my system to hibernate, the same message appears and the system state will not be persisted.

Comment: Why on earth was this done by the installation in the first place?!

Answer (score 4):

I was getting the same error message. I tried what is being suggested **[here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/341979/what-to-do-about-the-disk-drive-for-dev-mapper-cryptswap1-is-not-ready-yet-or)** but the error persisted.
(By the way, instructions given in one of the links [there](http://punygeek.blogspot.nl/2012/10/ubuntu-1204-how-to-solve-disk-drive-for.html) is incomplete. Read comments from others underneath the post and that should take you to the right direction).

I came across **[this post](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2164313&p=12740244#post12740244)** that solved the problem for me by delaying *swapon*.

### I did the following:

```
sudo gedit /etc/fstab
```

I changed the line

```
/dev/mapper/cryptswap1 none swap sw 0 0
```

to read

```
/dev/mapper/cryptswap1 none swap sw,noauto 0 0
```

Then

```
sudo gedit /etc/rc.local
```

and immediately before

```
exit 0
```

added these two lines:

```
sleep 5
swapon /dev/mapper/cryptswap1
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this helps? Seems to be the answer for a few similar problems:

[Puny Geek: Ubuntu 12.04 - How to solve "The disk drive for /dev/mapper/cryptswap1 is not ready yet or not present" error at boot](http://punygeek.blogspot.com/2012/10/ubuntu-1204-how-to-solve-disk-drive-for.html)

Answer (score 0):

I got same error message when I had NO ENCRYPTED SWAP at all, just normal swap, after an upgrade from 13.10 to 14.04. I checked with Gparted & realized that it wasn't recognizing my former swap partition, so I formatted it as linux-swap, rebooted and it was done.

Answer (score 0):

I could not find convenient solution to this problem.

I run Ubuntu 14.04 and that helped to me:

```
 sudo mkswap /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1
```

You can then mount your swap using:

```
 sudo swapon -a
```

That's it. 
After restarting your machine you should've swap mounted, because it should've been already configured in /etc/fstab.