# "The harddrive for /dev/mapper/cryptswap1 is not yet ready or non existent."

Tags: encryption, swap

Two days ago I installed the Ubuntu 12.04 LTS on my laptop, now I have got a big problem I cannot sort out, even by reading and checking what some of you stated in the explanations.

Problem: (Its in german so the translation may not be totally equal) "The harddrive for /dev/mapper/cryptswap1 is not yet ready or non existent."

As asked : `nano /etc/fstab`

```
  GNU nano 2.2.6             Datei: /etc/fstab                                  

 # /etc/fstab: static file system information.  
 #  
 # Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a  
 # device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices  
 # that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).  
 #  
 # <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>  
 proc            /proc           proc    nodev,noexec,nosuid 0       0  
 # / was on /dev/sda1 during installation  
UUID=ec755811-c3d0-4ffa-99d4-cb23a07a706a /               ext4    errors=remoun$  
 # swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation  
 #UUID=8085f746-2ae9-48ad-82aa-35fd8ace1009 none            swap    sw          $  
 /dev/mapper/cryptswap1 none swap sw 0 0
```

Comment: Hy K7AAY, thanks for the comment!It is Ubuntu 12.04. Concerning "nano/etc/fstab", do I have to write "sudo" or something else in front? I tried but it says "bash: nano/etc/fstab: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden" (Data or directory not found)

Comment: nano (space) /etc/fstab will open it as Read Only, which is all you need to do at this point. Sudo? Maybe later if we need to change things.

Comment: Adding a space at the beginning of each line and two spaces at the end of each line keeps the AskUbuntu software from thinking you wanted boldfaced or large type - something you never know until you run into it.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, edited already :)

Comment: Thanks for the solution of problem number 1. I am trying to edit the line putting the hash icon in front of "cryptswap1 .." but I cannot save it. It is step number 2. This is turning out to be quite complicated :S

Answer (score 0):

To resolve the [cryptswap1 issue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/341979/what-to-do-about-the-disk-drive-for-dev-mapper-cryptswap1-is-not-ready-yet-or), open a terminal window and then do

> sudo nano /etc/fstab

and comment out the inappropriate line with cryptswap1 with an octothorpe ( # ) in the first column. Then make sure you have a line for the standard swap partition, like

> /dev/hda5 swap    swap    defaults    0   0

Save the file and exit with

> Ctrl-O
>   Ctrl-X

and reboot the system.