# I need to "swapon" after each boot

Tags: partitioning, swap

I just clean-installed Ubuntu (12.04.4 lts) for my first time about a week ago and have been having problems with swap from the get-go. Initially, I was receiving the error message "The disk drive for /dev/mapper/cryptswap1 is not ready yet or not present" during boot. In Gparted, I could see my hard drive as well as a bunch of empty space that was supposed to be my swap. After mucking about on the internet and such, I tried the answer to this person's [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/341979/what-to-do-about-the-disk-drive-for-dev-mapper-cryptswap1-is-not-ready-yet-or), which is really just a summary of this [post](http://punygeek.blogspot.ca/2012/10/ubuntu-1204-how-to-solve-disk-drive-for.html).

I went through the steps and had to re-do them a bit because there were some missing steps in the comments, but I at least got the error message to go away (hooray) although I still face the problem in the title. At every boot I need to "swapon" the swap partition in Gparted (I'm sure there's another way, but it's all I know for now). What do?

I'll post the outputs of any commands you want as long as you show me how to paste the results here properly :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can edit /etc/fstab and add swap

/dev/partition              none          swap      defaults              0      0

If this don't work you can put in /etc/rc.local command

swapon /dev/partition

Maybe this solve your problem

Comment: Could you elaborate a little bit? Just because really haven't used terminals and the like very much before. Like if I've understood correctly, you're saying that I should use "sudo gedit /etc/fstab" and just write /dev/partition none swap defaults 0 0 at the bottom? (I'll be replace "partition" with "sda2" for my case as it's the name of my swap drive)

Comment: Yes. My English is very bad. Try to solve your problem on this way https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-add-swap-on-ubuntu-12-04

Comment: That's okay, I did what you said above and it worked! Thanks a bunch!