# Encrypted Swap Partition for 14.04

Tags: partitioning, 14.04, encryption, swap

How can I produce an encrypted Swap Partition for 14.04 ?
All the advices I saw here are for versions <14.04 and do not work for me.

I tried a lot but nothing lasted longer than a reboot.

On installation I decided to encrypt my home and 9 GiB partition for swap but this swap was never used by Kubuntu. Gparted finds an "unknown filesystem".

I many times formated it as swap, edited `fstab` and `crypttab` and used all the tricks mentioned in different answers here. The often mentioned PunyGeek letter does not work for me probably because `/etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume` does not even exist on my system.

Answer (score 19):

After some more trying and bootups I figured out that this seems to work for me:

**NOTE:** REPLACE the X in sdaX with YOUR partition-number! UUIDs did not work for me!

Install necessary packages:

```
sudo apt-get install cryptsetup
```

Format your partition to SWAP

```
sudo swapoff -a
sudo cryptsetup -d /dev/urandom create cryptswap /dev/sdaX
sudo mkswap -f /dev/mapper/cryptswap -v1 -Lhello-swap
```

Add or edit the following line to `/etc/crypttab`:

```
cryptswap /dev/sdaX /dev/urandom swap
```

Add or edit the line in `/etc/fstab`:

```
/dev/mapper/cryptswap none swap sw 0 0
```

Re-enable swap:

```
sudo swapon -s
```

Confirm that swap is enabled:

```
free -m | grep Swap:
```

or check your System Monitor app in the Resources tab.

Comment: not working after reboot

Comment: the -v1 argument not effective since only one version is working now

Comment: I like adding a label to partitions so that it later reminds me that this was something I made and not automatically done by the system.  So I'd add something like this to the command: -L$HOSTNAME-swap

Comment: It probably misses an `update-initramfs -u` at the end, in order for the initamfs cryptroot hook script to embed the kernel drivers (aes, sha256, etc) in the initramfs, to be effective after reboot.

Answer (score 3):

Using 14.04LTS, I had the same problem as tomasb, that encrypted swap wasn't on after reboot.  I discovered that /etc/crypttab wasn't being processed because the necessary init.d scripts (cryptdisks and cryptdisks-early) weren't installed.

I solved that problem with

```
$ sudo apt-get install cryptsetup
```

Rebooted and I had encrypted swap.

Comment: I added this step to the accepted answer so everything is contained in there.

Answer (score 0):

This actually worked for me, but i'm not sure if it is a good solution (multiple users):

```
sudo gedit /etc/init/cryptdisks.conf
```

search line near bottom of the file containing `do_start` and add

```
/etc/init.d/cryptdisks reload
```

just below;

assuming all stuff in michel's answer is done

Comment: probably better solution is to use ordinary swap file located in encrypted home for each user and start swapping after login; have found this bug since Ubuntu 7.04

Comment: First of all, this bug has definitely not existed since 7.04. I have used encrypted swap with no problems in 9.10, 10.04, and 12.04. Secondly using encrypted swap is supposed to be more secure than a swap file in a home directory, since encrypted swap is done with a key, which is not persisted across reboots. Finally in order for a clean shutdown to happen as reliably as possible, it need to be possible to unmount all file systems, even if there is insufficient RAM to disable swap. In this respect a swap file will always be less reliable than a swap partition.