# Create randomly encrypted swap when installing 14.04.1?

Tags: 14.04, partitioning, encryption, swap

How do I create a randomly encrypted swap partition when doing a clean install of 14.04.1?

This option was available in the text-based partman in 12.04, but I can't find it in the graphical partition editor in the 14.04.1 installer.

My goal is three partitions: /boot, swap (random-key encrypted), / (passphrase encrypted).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Thank you, liquidat. That was not quite what I was looking for, but it did help me figure it out. Here is what I did, which seems to have worked:

At installation, set up three partitions:

- `/dev/sda1`: 512 Mb Ext2, mapped to `/boot`.
- `/dev/sda2`: 4096 Mb unused partition, of type Linux (`0x83`).
- `/dev/sda3`: Remaining space encrypted Ext4, mapped to `/` (file system root).

This installed Ubuntu without a swap space. After installation, I followed the instructions from [Encrypted Swap Partition for 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/463661/encrypted-swap-partition-for-14-04) to install a randomly encrypted swap partition in `/dev/sda2`. I modified the commands slightly to follow the example from my 12.04 installation:

```
$ sudo cryptsetup -d /dev/urandom create sda2_crypt /dev/sda2
$ sudo mkswap -f /dev/mapper/sda2_crypt
```

Add/edit the following line to `/etc/crypttab`:

```
sda2_crypt /dev/sda2 /dev/urandom cipher=aes-cbc-essiv:sha256,size=256,swap
```

Add/edit the line in `/etc/fstab`:

```
/dev/mapper/sda2_crypt none swap sw 0 0
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, this is not possible during installation with the help of the GUI tools. You need to change to console during installation, or enable encryption afterwards. There is a how-to, even respecting hibernation if you want, at [Enable Hibernate With Encrypted Swap](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnableHibernateWithEncryptedSwap).