# Ubuntu 16.04 - How to make an encrypted swap after install

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, encryption, swap

I have enabled full disk encryption on Ubuntu 16.04 by following this [guide](http://www.hecticgeek.com/2012/10/how-to-setup-encrypted-ubuntu-installation/). But I have not yet created a swap partition for it. I would like to setup an encrypted swap partition, what I have found online is the following (Please correct me if I am wrong) -:

Steps taken from [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnableHibernateWithEncryptedSwap).

**First** format the swap partition as an encrypted swap, but then here how do I link it to my original passphrase for booting the system ? I don't want to have a passphrase for unlocking the system and then one for the swap partition separately. Also I would like to use the same encryption key used for all the other LUKS partition.

```
sudo cryptsetup luksFormat --cipher aes-xts-plain64 --verify-passphrase --key-size 256 /dev/sdXN
```

**Second** I think is adding to the list of encrypted partitions (I am not sure what the function of luksOpen is yet,)

```
sudo cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sdXN cryptswap1
```

Third is marking the partition as swap-:

```
sudo mkswap /dev/mapper/cryptswap1
```

And next steps are as in the tutorial.

Now before I try anything **I want to know is this the correct way of setting up an encrypted swap for 16.04** ? Also I would like them all to be in the same setup if possible, like if **I could configure the encrypted swap at install time, what would be great.**

Also there is another set of instructions over [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/463661/encrypted-swap-partition-for-14-04), but that brings up the same questions that how do I use the same passphrase and encryption scheme as the other partitions. Also as given in the comments the `-v1` option is causing problems.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F0b4I89LY5E