# the disk drive for /dev/mapper/cryptswap1 is not ready yet or not present is showing

Tags: boot, swap

On a new elementary os installation the swap is not available. I tried all the remedies offered here: [What to do about "the disk drive for /dev/mapper/cryptswap1 is not ready yet or not present"?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/341979/what-to-do-about-the-disk-drive-for-dev-mapper-cryptswap1-is-not-ready-yet-or)
but nothing seems to do the trick. After I run all the steps and reboot the same message appears and prior to rebooting the swap indeed shows in 'free -m'.

After rebooting it shows:
`Mem:          1613       1028        584          0         34        504
-/+ buffers/cache:        488       1124
Swap:            0          0          0`

I too had to reboot between formatting the partition as linux-swap in gparted as otherwise it wouldn't do it.

What else to try, nothing seems to help...?

Comment: Are you using 14.04? Things changed between 12.04 and 14.04, so any answers from before 14.04 are unlikely to fully cover the issues you would be facing in 14.04. Also this sounds like a possible duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/596813/can-ubuntu-14-04-use-encrypted-swap-without-resorting-to-unofficial-hacks

Comment: Does http://askubuntu.com/a/597153/284919 work for you?

Comment: @kasperd Wonderful, the first one did it :) It still shows the crappy mistake while booting but swap is now on:
'Swap:         1952          0       1952'

Comment: We're sorry, but this site is all about Ubuntu and its official derivatives as posted on https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases so Elementary Luna is off-topic here as well. However, on http://unix.stackexchange.com, a sister site to Ask Ubuntu, they're very good at all varieties of Linux and Unix, so you might be better off there.  ;-)

Comment: That's fab, @Fabby :) thank you very much - will use the new site for any further questions