# The disk drive for /dev/mapper/cryptswap1 is not ready yet or not present

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, encryption

I re-installed Ubuntu as the only OS on my PC, deleting both Windows 7 and my previous Ubuntu 14.04 installation. But now, when starting my computer I see this message:

[image: message when starting the computer]

What does it mean?

Did I do something wrong?

I performed a pretty much standard clean installation, deleting everything.

A few things that come to my mind about doing anything different from my previous Ubuntu installation is that I checked the "Encrypt my Home folder" option and I ejected the installation CD when I got the message "Installation complete, please restart the computer" because of my BIOS setting being to start from the CD-Rom boot.

How can I 'fix' this (if there's anything to fix at all)?

I should say that Ubuntu feels a little more slow than it used to be on my previous installation, could this have anything to do with it?

I already did a full software update, still the same message.

PS: Sorry for the low quality of the picture, my camera is a potato, hope you get to see what is says.

A user pointed out to me the fact that this question is a duplicate of [What to do about "the disk drive for /dev/mapper/cryptswap1 is not ready yet or not present"?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/341979/what-to-do-about-the-disk-drive-for-dev-mapper-cryptswap1-is-not-ready-yet-or), and there's a link to a [possible answer](http://punygeek.blogspot.com/2012/10/ubuntu-1204-how-to-solve-disk-drive-for.html) on it but I really don't understand what that answer is saying, can someone PLEASE guide me through it?

I'm currently on step 4

> Install gparted. Run it and format your swap partition as linux-swap. Make sure to get the right partition; if you get the wrong one, you'll lose possibly important data! The line you commented out in crypttab should give the correct partition name (it comes right after `/dev/`

But I don't really understand what it is I should do, here's an image to my gparted partitions:

[image: gparted]

I managed to do the steps 4 and 5. but now I'm on step 6

> In the file /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume, find the line that says `RESUME=UUID=` followed by letters and numbers like (but not identical to) ..... from the last step. Replace them with ..... (i.e., with the letters and numbers mkswap gave after UUID=.) What does it mean by "In the file...". Where is that file, how do I open it?

I lost the "UUID" string and couldn't find it anymore so I just re-installed Ubuntu, left the "Encrypt my Home folder" option unchecked and the message just went away, I did understand eventually what the solution was because of the help obtained from [Rohith Madhavan](https://askubuntu.com/users/348400/rohith-madhavan) but because I couldn't find the "UUID" string again I got frustrated; I'm going to mark the question as solved though because of being another question's duplicate witch has been already solved.

By the way, I didn't removed the CD after the "Installation complete" message and, of course, there was a message telling me to do so when starting.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What to do about "the disk drive for /dev/mapper/cryptswap1 is not ready yet or not present"?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/341979/what-to-do-about-the-disk-drive-for-dev-mapper-cryptswap1-is-not-ready-yet-or)

Comment: I think it is, exactly, but I understand pretty much nothing about the solution, could you guide me?
where it says 

"2. Open /etc/crypttab (e.g., sudo nano -w /etc/crypttab or sudo -H gedit /etc/cryptab for a GUI editor) and put a # at the beginning of the line that starts with cryptswap1. Save the file."

How do I save the file?

Comment: `nano` is a command line text editor. To save a file after modification in `nano`, you need to press `Ctrl`+`X` followed by `Y` and `Enter` keys.

Comment: Great! I was able to save both files after commenting them, now, how do I do step 4? I already installed gparted but don't know what to do with it.
[Here](http://i.imgur.com/JhlEjAF.png)'s an image of my gparted thing.

Comment: To edit the file - `sudo nano /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume`

Comment: I ended up re-installing Ubuntu, thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message indicates that the system was not able to mount the encrypted `swap` partition.

**EDIT -**

This question is a possible duplicate of [What to do about "the disk drive for /dev/mapper/cryptswap1 is not ready yet or not present"?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/341979/what-to-do-about-the-disk-drive-for-dev-mapper-cryptswap1-is-not-ready-yet-or)

Kindly refer to the particular question for the solution.

Comment: What does that mean, is that a problem?

Comment: Was your previous Ubuntu installation encrypted?

Comment: No, it was not.