# the disk drive for /dev/mapper/cryptswap1 is not ready yet or not present error on startup

Tags: 14.04, boot, dual-boot, mount

On start-up I get the error:

```
The disk drive for /dev/mapper/cryptswap1 is not ready yet or not present
```

but then Ubuntu starts normally.

I recently installed Ubuntu 14.04 in dual boot with Windows 7 using a pendrive. I used `rufus` to burn the iso on the pendrive.

I was going to try what was written [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/341979/what-to-do-about-the-disk-drive-for-dev-mapper-cryptswap1-is-not-ready-yet-or) but I checked the various files before actually running any commands or doing any edits and found a few differences. Also the file `resume` does not exist in `/etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d`.

I attached a screenshot of `fstab`, `crypttab`, `gparted` of `sda` and the contents of `conf.d`. (I have only one physical hard drive).

This is the gparted screen shot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yXCqA.png

This is /etc/crypttab: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nr0XG.png

This is /etc/fstab: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TLExI.png

This is /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d folder: https://i.stack.imgur.com/l8fw0.png

*How should I enable swap on an encrypted volume?*

Comment: Answers? Anybody?

Comment: Please  don't use screen shots to show text files. Use http://paste.ubuntu.com instead so the text is searchable... ;-)
And I'm sorry and, please, blame it on me: I'm confused and confusing...  But...  *What's your question???* :/

Comment: It seems that my computer is unable to use the swap partition. How to fix that.

Comment: A comment there says the computer didn't start up after doing that

Comment: It is not well written there. Can't understand some stuff

Comment: Could you please specify what exactly you don't understand?

Comment: Sorry for the trouble. I got it. But is it safe?

Comment: Yes!  Safer then what you had before...  ;-)

Comment: i tried it, and the error still appears but for a very short time : less than a second

Comment: I should have told you from the start: That's normal if you're running this from a USB stick: It just takes a little bit more time to mount an encrypted swap then a normal swap, so you can consider that a "warning" and not an "error"...  As long as you followed the instructions in the duplicate, you're fine!  ;-)