# Ubuntu 14.04LTS. How to solve "The disk drive for /dev/mapper/cryptswap1 is not ready yet or not present" error at boot

Tags: 14.04

so i have reinstalled my ubuntu OS and got my home directory encrypted during installation. then everytime i load ubuntu os i see this error pop up before boot.

"The disk drive for /dev/mapper/cryptswap1 is not ready yet or not present"

Comment: Please read this : http://askubuntu.com/questions/341979/what-to-do-about-the-disk-drive-for-dev-mapper-cryptswap1-is-not-ready-yet-or

Comment: i'm new to ubuntu. and i cant really follow instructions that well when it comes to commands lol. can you guide me through the link you gave me? is there a way we can chat?

Comment: i can't, i need 10 more rep to chat :/