# Slow boot on version 20.10 after installing xanmod kernel

Tags: boot, nvidia, kernel, encryption

I tried disabling the *network manager service* with no luck. It takes over a minute a half to boot. Here is the output from

**systemd-analyze critical-chain**

```
graphical.target @1min 35.521s
└─multi-user.target @1min 35.521s
  └─plymouth-quit-wait.service @1min 31.228s +4.292s
    └─systemd-user-sessions.service @1min 31.219s +4ms
      └─network.target @1min 31.217s
        └─wpa_supplicant.service @1min 31.689s +10ms
          └─dbus.service @1min 30.455s
            └─basic.target @1min 30.442s
              └─sockets.target @1min 30.442s
                └─uuidd.socket @1min 30.442s
                  └─sysinit.target @1min 30.370s
                    └─systemd-backlight@leds:tpacpi::kbd_backlight.service @952>
                      └─system-systemd\x2dbacklight.slice @538ms
                        └─system.slice @175ms
                          └─-.slice @175ms
lines 1-18/18 (END)
```

**systemd-analyze**

```
Startup finished in 5.415s (kernel) + 1min 35.528s (userspace) = 1min 40.943s 
graphical.target reached after 1min 35.521s in userspace
```

**systemd-analyze blame**

```
4.292s plymouth-quit-wait.service                          
 937ms systemd-logind.service                              
 846ms accounts-daemon.service                             
 826ms networkd-dispatcher.service                         
 798ms udisks2.service                                     
 765ms bluetooth.service                                   
 765ms avahi-daemon.service                                
 760ms NetworkManager.service                              
 755ms system76-power.service                              
 752ms polkit.service                                      
 743ms switcheroo-control.service                          
 739ms thermald.service                                    
 649ms gpu-manager.service                                 
 647ms dev-mapper-data\x2droot.device                      
 639ms apport.service                                      
 634ms grub-common.service                                 
 624ms rsyslog.service                                     
 620ms lm-sensors.service                                  
 606ms e2scrub_reap.service                                
 557ms vpnagentd.service                                   
 504ms fwupd.service                                       
 213ms apparmor.service                                    
 203ms systemd-rfkill.service                              
lines 1-23
```

**System specifications**

- Distro: Ubuntu
- Disk encryption: enabled
- Hardware: Thinkpad X1 Extreme, 8th gen i7 CPU, 32GB RAM, NVIDIA 1050 Ti
- xanmod kernel version: stable version 5.10.35

It used to boot fast even with disk encryption enabled in the default kernel that came with the Pop os, after installing xanmod kernel I'm facing this slow boot issue. I tried booting from the default kernel and then even removed it but no help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the problem is with the swap partition having different UUID in the configuration files. The system had it waiting for full 90 seconds before entering the login screen is because it was searching for a swap partition that didn't exist.

So a fix to this problem is to boot the system into the recovery mode and check to see if it is searching for a swap partition, if it does the configuration files need to be updated with the proper UUID of the swap partition that does actually exist. If you wish not to have a swap partition then feel free to remove/comment outlines that will be looking for a swap from those files.

This post helps you in finding where those configuration files are and what/how you need to edit them:
[What to do about “the disk drive for /dev/mapper/cryptswap1 is not ready yet or not present”?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/341979/what-to-do-about-the-disk-drive-for-dev-mapper-cryptswap1-is-not-ready-yet-or/342002#342002)