# “the disk drive for /dev/mapper/cryptswap1 is not ready yet or not present”

Tags: boot, partitioning, mount

I have tried the solution as presented here [What to do about "the disk drive for /dev/mapper/cryptswap1 is not ready yet or not present"?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/341979/what-to-do-about-the-disk-drive-for-dev-mapper-cryptswap1-is-not-ready-yet-or) as well as its original source  http://punygeek.blogspot.com/2012/10/ubuntu-1204-how-to-solve-disk-drive-for.html here several times.

What's happening is that every time I reformat my linux-swap with Gparted, it works perfectly well as long as my session lasts. Whenever I reboot, the swap partition becomes "unknown" as displayed in Gparted, needless to say “the disk drive for /dev/mapper/cryptswap1 is not ready yet or not present” is still present.

Comment: This worked for me: [How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows)

Comment: I am still having the problem after running the Punygeek process - it works up to the point where I reboot the system, then comes back with the same error again, and Gparted reports that the linux-swap partition goes back to being unknown.

Answer (score 2):

Try this if on 12.04, probably work for other distros too. Already answered here:

["Disk drive for dev/mapper/cryptswap 1 is not ready"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/289858/disk-drive-for-dev-mapper-cryptswap-1-is-not-ready)

You could also look here:

http://punygeek.blogspot.nl/2012/10/ubuntu-1204-how-to-solve-disk-drive-for.html