# Very slow boot Ubuntu 14.04 Asus laptop

Tags: 14.04, boot, asus

Quick question here. I've got Ubuntu 14.04 on a Asus U36JC (i5, dual boot Windows 7). I think I started this laptop on Ubuntu 11 or 12 and have updated always without wiping the hd. It used to boot very quickly and is now...well. slow. really slow.

It also shows a [cryptswap](https://askubuntu.com/questions/289858/disk-drive-for-dev-mapper-cryptswap-1-is-not-ready) error only sometimes when booting. I've tried various fixes, with no luck.

So my question -- how can I go about figuring out what is slowing up my boot? I'm moderately Ubuntu literate -- by no means advanced but I can work through fixes from the forums very easily. I've tried all sorts of stuff for this setup and haven't figured it out.

Any ideas on how to go about solving this, short of just wiping and installing fresh, would be very appreciated. Thanks!!

Comment: A fresh install seems to be the best option since upgrading from a previous release, especially from one that is 2-3 years old , may tend to cause such problems.